# python datetime and date comparison

Tags: python

Based on the example I found [here](http://howto.pui.ch/post/37471158372/fetch-publicly-available-google-calendar-data-with) I want to grab icalendar data and process it. This my code so far:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from icalendar import Calendar
import urllib
import time

ics = urllib.urlopen('https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/xy/basic.ics').read()
ical1 = Calendar.from_ical(ics)
for vevent in ical1.subcomponents:
    if vevent.name == "VEVENT":
        title = str(vevent.get('SUMMARY').encode('utf-8'))
        start = vevent.get('DTSTART').dt   # datetime
        end = vevent.get('DTEND').dt       # datetime

        print title
        print start
        print end
        print type(start)
        print "---"
```

It is fetching the title and start+end date from my google calender. This working and the output looks like this:

```
This is a Test Title
2012-12-20 15:00:00+00:00
2012-12-20 18:00:00+00:00
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
---
Another Title
2012-12-10
2012-12-11
<type 'datetime.date'>
---
    ...
```

As you can see the start and end date can be of type `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.date`. It depends on whether I have an entry in google calender for 2 whole days (then it is a `datetime.date`) or for a time period e.g. 3 hours (then it is a `datetime.datetime`. I need to only print dates/datetimes from today and for the next 4 weeks. I had problems comparing dates and datetimes (its seems like it is not possible) so I failed to do that. How can I compare datetimes and dates conserving the data types? If I need to "cast" them, its ok. I was not able to print "today + 4 weeks", only "4 weeks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert to a common type for comparison. Since both datetime's and date's have dates in common, it makes sense to convert -> date types. Just extract the date() from the datetime. For example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date(2014, 2, 22) == datetime.datetime.now().date()
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Datetime objects can return an appropriate date object by calling date on them: `start.date()` which then can be compared to another date object: `start.date() < datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(4*7)`